# Runtime error 91 When Setting Variables VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

When I run the following subroutine in Excel VBA I get this error:

> *Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set*.

The line where the error occurs is attempting to convert a letter (specifically to reference a column) to the corresponding number of that column. I successfully use the exact same approach earlier in my program with different variables, which is why I feel so stuck with this bug. Any input is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub Merge_Duplicate_Columns()

MsgBox ("The summed values of the two columns will automatically be placed in the firstCol selection, so choose accordingly.")

'Dim firstCol As Integer
'Dim secondCol As Integer
Dim firstLetter As String
Dim secondLetter As String

firstLetter = InputBox("Please enter the letter of the first column you would like to merge:", "First Choice")
secondLetter = InputBox("Please enter the letter of the second column you would like to merge:", "Second Choice")

'firstCol = source.Range(firstLetter & 1).Column         'need to set variables somehow
'secondCol = source.Range(secondLetter & 1).Column

'firstCol = source.Columns(firstLetter).Column
'secondCol = source.Columns(secondLetter).Column

Dim i As Integer
For i = rowStart To rowEnd
    source.Cells(i, firstLetter).Value = source.Cells(i, firstLetter).Value + source.Cells(i, secondLetter).Value
Next i
source.Columns(secondLetter).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Jo3.png)

Comment: Just checking, have you `Set source = ...` somewhere earlier?

Comment: Yes, I set it to reference the main sheet of data that I'm working with

Comment: `Cells` can take a `String` reference for the column - you don't need to do the column letter to column number conversion.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. When I take out the conversion the error still occurs, but not until the first iteration of the loop code runs (I switched out the firstCols for firstLetter and secondCols for secondLetter). What does this mean?

Comment: What column letters are you typing in?

Comment: The ones I've been testing the most are L and M, though I've been trying others also. All of them are within the dataset and have data within them to be summed

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Maybe edit your question with all of your (revised) code, including the line where you `Set source = ...`? And a screenshot? `Debug.Print` `firstLetter` and `secondLetter` to make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: Just edited it to show the set source line in addition to a screenshot showing the highlighted line where the error occurs and the current state of the variables in question (which are accurate to my selections). Hopefully this helps

Comment: There's no `Set source = Worksheets("Source File")` in your screenshot?? And how do you get `rowStart` and `rowEnd`?

Comment: It's because the Set source line is earlier in the program, as I said. It isn't needed in this sub. rowStart and rowEnd are public variables that are also correctly implemented and valued.

Comment: I'm confused - add `Debug.Print Source.Name` before your `InputBox`'s. Does the new line throw an error?

Comment: Yes, the same error

Comment: How/where are you doing `Set source = ...` earlier? Since that new line throws an error, `Merge_Duplicate_Columns` doesn't know what `Source` is. The easiest fix is to `Set Source` within this `Sub`. Why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: I have that line at the very beginning of my first sub, and only there. I didn't continue to put it in subs because it appeared to work in the other subs that didn't have that line and weren't being called by the original sub. When I insert that line into this sub it gives a 1004 error on the first iteration of the loop

Comment: I forgot to mention that I DID declare source as a global worksheet... I also have option explicit already, is there anything else that could possibly be causing the error??

Comment: Do you `Set Source = ...` within a  `Workbook_Open` sub?

Comment: No, is that a problem?

Comment: Update: I've edited the code a little bit (specifically in the loop) to try to make it simpler, yet I still get the 1004 error